# Reusing disposable objects in three.js, best practice to avoid memory leaks

Tags: angular, three.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

To reuse materials I instantiate it globally in an angular modal dialog component file and use it in the component.

Now, if I close and reopen the dialog, all previous instances remain in memory.
This happens iff I use the material in the component.

I tried to dispose the material each time before unmounting the component. That works, the garbage collector will free up the component storage properly.

But for me, my workaround looks strange, because I have to dispose the same material each time after using it. Is this a proper way?

In my understanding, the material is an immutable and there is no need for the material to know its context rsp. holding a reference to the component. And so the garbage collector could remove the component from memory, but does'nt. Am I wrong?

What is the best practice to reuse disposable objects in three.js?

Many thanks for clarificarion and hints

code: test-view.ts

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
...

export const mat = new MeshNormalMaterial(); // globally create for reusing

export class TestViewNative {

  async ngAfterViewInit() {
    ...
    const mesh = new Mesh(geo, mat); // using the material causes memory leak
    ...
  }
  ...
  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    mat.dispose() // strange here cause mat is global, but it avoids the memory leak
  }


}
```

Comment: Probably not an answer to all your questions, but take a look at https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-dispose-of-objects

Comment: Also, materials are immutable only to a degree. Making small changes to materials during runtime is certainly possible: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-update-things

Comment: yes materials are not really immutable. I mean that I assumed that the material will not be changed from three if I pass it to the mesh rsp. it should not hold a reference to the mesh which would prevent the garbage collector from freeing the mesh and the angular component.
Maby I am wrong? But why do the Material need to know or reffer to its context, or do I have overseen other things?